# variable defined as column type of reference table but not calculated or initialized in oracle pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a variable 'v_bas_unused_commt' in old code, which I am trying to re-write, as following before BEGIN statement of old procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USB."BAS2_WIRES_SEG" (v_run_date number default 0)
 IS
v_bas_unused_commt  WIRES_DATA.bas_unused_commt%TYPE;

--WIRES_DATA is table getting updated by this proc
```

Issue is: It is not doing anything inside proc with variable: 'v_bas_unused_commt' (i.e. this variable is not being used at all except being passed as an input.)  and then it is being passed to a function as an parameter for calculating following field:

```
v_bas_eb_expected_loss := bas2_el_calc (rec.CUR_BOOK_BAL,v_BAS_UNUSED_COMMT,v_BAS_PD,v_BAS_LGD,V_BAS_EAD);

--look at input 2.
```

I wanted to confirm when I re-write this code, Should I use 0 in place of v_BAS_UNUSED_COMMT or sth else? I tried using original column name BAS_UNUSED_COMMT from Table WIRES_DATA, in place of v_BAS_UNUSED_COMMT , but that column has values and it is resulting in different values for v_bas_eb_expected_loss after calculation. However, when I wrote

```
v_bas_unused_commt  WIRES_DATA.bas_unused_commt%TYPE;
and passed v_bas_unused_commt as input, same as old code, differences disappeared.
```

I thought it may be because v_bas_unused_commt  is always 0 but wanted to confirm before I replace it in final procedure

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable declared but not initialized will have NULL value (different from zero), unless somewhere in the procedure a different value has been attributed to it. With a simple test like this you can verify it right before making your function call:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-06-25 12:01:23> create table t1(col1 varchar2(8));

Table created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-06-25 12:01:23> create or replace procedure fsitja.pr_test is
  2  v_empty t1.col1%type;
  3  begin
  4    if v_empty is null then
  5      dbms_output.put_line('I AM NULL');
  6    end if;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-06-25 12:01:23> begin fsitja.pr_test; end;
  2  /
I AM NULL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You should probably use NULL. But please do check that it is indeed passing a NULL before you make the change.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Just replaced it and it is working.